# Custom Listener which is always going to execute inside @Test annotation in TestNG

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I have a scenario where I need to generate a key first line inside @Test method. And I need to give generic solution to achieve this. Already we have custom class file which is generate a token, and It should be generated inside @Test method.

As of now we have the below lines of code in all @Test methods. It seems to be duplicate and wanna give some generic solution on this. We would like to create a listener which is gonna execute once @Test method is progress, and before execute the first line of code actually present in that method.

Here is the code :

```
  @Test
  public void getSearchMach()
   {
   //The AutoKeyGenerator is a class which has getKey() method and return 
   //type as String
       String getkey=AutoKeyGenerator.getKey();
       //Some logic will go here.
   }
```

The above line should be placed first line in all test methods. I don't wanna repeat everywhere and create a listener which is going to do same activity in smart way. like A listener will execute the line and then execute remaining lines. I have been used @BeforeMethod, and @BeforeClass, and @BeforeSuite which is not working and returning null as string value.

Comment: As far as I understood from the query, you can declare the variable(getKey) as static inside the class and make sure you never define a local variable inside test method with same name. If this is not the issue please provide more information on the issue.

Comment: Its still duplicate if I created a generic method and I should call It all the @Test methods. I don't wanna repeat the code in all Test methods. Instead of I wanna keep it in listener which is gonna do the getKey() operation while test is invoked.

Comment: Let me give a example on what I am trying to explain as per from my side.

Comment: @ArrchanaMohan - What exactly do you do with this value ? Is it being used in every `@Test` that you have ?

Comment: Yes. Its signature key which is required to pass in every @Test method. Each test method represent different API call and end of the method will assert the response payload. That's how we design our script. It required to call the getKey() in every method and pass the key as header in request payload.

Answer (score 0):

We can declare the variable as static inside class. Here is the code snippet :

```
public class Testing {

    static String getKey;

    @BeforeTest
    public void set() {
        getKey = getKeyNow();
    }

    private String getKeyNow() {
        // Do Something
        return "Hi There";
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        System.out.println(getKey);
        assertEquals(1, 1);
    }
}
```

Let me know if this solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a result listener by extending TestListenerAdapter and overriding onTestStart method which is "Invoked each time before a test will be invoked."

```
public class TestResultsListener extends TestListenerAdapter {

@Override
public void onTestStart(final ITestResult tr) {
    String getkey=AutoKeyGenerator.getKey();
   //Some logic will go here.
}
```

}